# MYSQL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE didn't update

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql on duplicate key statement.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO statistics (classify, apply) VALUES ('$classify', 1) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE apply = apply + 1");

id  classify  apply

1   A         1
```

but it didn't update the existing row and it keep add another row, Where is the problem?

Comment: Show your `CREATE TABLE` statement. Do you actually have a unique index on `classify`?

Comment: that would mean that what ever you inserted did not violate any key so a new record could be added. You will need to add some unique key or something - perhaps you could give as the dump of the show create table statistics and give us some data that you think should be instered and what should update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably the column `classify` is not `unique`. You need to have a `UNIQUE` field in the table to make `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` work. If you have not set one, you can execute this statement below.

```
ALTER TABLE statistics ADD CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (classify)
```

Comment: thx very much for the answer, what if i add country and year, should i set classify, country and year all unique?

Comment: You can create unique combinations of fields, yes, but you must first check if thats what you want. I'm not quite sure what `classify` is in your context, neither what it has to do with country and year.

Comment: Yes if you need a compound unique key `UNIQUE(Classify, Country, Year)`. Consider the following, `Classify, Country, Year`. If you have this set of record `1, US, 2001` is not duplicate with `1, US,  2000` since your constraint enforce on the 3 columns.

Answer (score 2):

`ON DUPLICATE KEY` will update a row only when you try to insert a record that would throw a duplicate keys error (like the name states). So this happens only if you are a using a unique key or a primary key for that column. It looks like you didn't created a unique key for the `classify` column.