# ON DUPLICATE KEY update when 3 columns's value match

Tags: php, mysql

```
INSERT INTO statistics(classify, country, ads, year) 
VALUES (:classify, :country, 1, :year) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ads = ads + 1
```

I have a query use `ON DUPLICATE KEY` and I set `unique key` to `classify`, `country` and `year`

however I need `UPDATE` only when `classify && country && year` all 3 have the same value from user input.

but it `UPDATE` the same row when one of the value is match

it become `classify || country || year`

This is what I need

```
 UPDATE statistics SET ads = ads + 1 
    WHERE classify='$classify' && country='$country' && year='$year'
```

any way to solve this problem?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE statistics ADD CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (Classify, Country, Year)` [from your **previous question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889176/mysql-on-duplicate-key-update-didnt-update)

Comment: i have try, but it didn't work

Comment: no, it should. please wait, i'll be creating fiddle.

Comment: @user2178521 *How* did you try it? It *should* work.

Comment: here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15ddf/1

Comment: @JW웃 In the question he says update if _one_ is a match, not all, I think that's the misunderstanding. Or I could be misreading the whole thing since the reverse is said elsewhere :)

Comment: no i mean all 3 need to match, like this WHERE classify='$classify' && country='$country' && year='$year'

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson he needs to match all fields.  `:)`

Comment: @JW웃 Ok, then the constraint should be it, I just read `when one of the value is match` and considered the possibility :)

Comment: it works now, i have no idea why it not working before, i delete the code and rewrite all again, but thx a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an unique constraint on (classify, country, year)

Comment: That is not an index per se but a constraint ;)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl The missing part _is_ that constraint. If it exists, the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` works, if not, it won't. Granted not explained, which it should be, but definitely the solution.